# What can I do about "missing ; before X" cascade of errors?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what did I do wrong, but suddenly my C++ project throws error for every single line of header files in certain part of that project. There must be something wrong in one of those files, but how am I supposed to find out which of these hundred errors is relevant?

Log looks like:

```
5>d:\ ... PROJECT_HOME ... \services\src\services\database\techcore\processes\inputdialog\../import/ImportDataSource.h(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
5>d:\ ... PROJECT_HOME ... \services\src\services\database\techcore\processes\inputdialog\../import/ImportDataSource.h(16): error C3861: 'mapping_': identifier not found
5>d:\ ... PROJECT_HOME ... \services\src\services\database\techcore\processes\inputdialog\../import/ImportDataSource.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '{'
5>d:\ ... PROJECT_HOME ... \services\src\services\database\techcore\processes\inputdialog\../import/ImportDataSource.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
5>c:\qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\include\qtwidgets\../../src/widgets/kernel/qaction.h(162): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
5>c:\qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\include\qtwidgets\../../src/widgets/kernel/qaction.h(162): error C2065: 'Hover' : undeclared identifier
5>d:\ ... PROJECT_HOME ... \services\src\services\database\techcore\processes\inputdialog\../import/ImportDataSource.h(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
5>c:\qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\include\qtwidgets\../../src/widgets/kernel/qaction.h(177): error C2065: 'QGraphicsWidget' : undeclared identifier
```

I intentionally copied part where errors also come from external libraries. The compiler has simply gone crazy. How can I resolve this? How do I find the place that causes this cascade of errors? Is there some validator that could process the files and give mi some hints? I went through most of the files manually and they seem to be correct.

This is not the first time this happened to me, so I decided it's time to ask how to generally solve these problems.

Comment: You should look at the very first error. All others are irrelevant (unless you can understand exactly where they come from). Look at code at and immediately before the line mentioned in the first error message.

Comment: Making a [mcve] normally helps

Comment: Enabling fatal errors (`-Wfatal-errors` on GCC, probably has an equivalent on MSVC) prevents the compilation from carrying on and compiling more files, which cuts down on the output volume. Then it's a matter of locating the first reported error and searching backwards (descending into `#include`d files, too). The typo is generally not far from there.

Comment: I found the error. It was one missing `:` in one of the files. Looking forward to answer that allows one to solve this without analyzing every character in every file. The error wasn't in the log at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver MCVE makes no sense when one asks for debugging practice. If you do not understand the question, maybe you're not competent to answe it anyhow...

Comment: @TomášZato I am not saying he needs to give us an mcve.  I am saying creating one normally helps to find these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the "compiler going crazy" is a symptom that the compiler has encountered a significant number of errors, still has more code to process in the affected source file (aka compilation unit).

When it encounters an problem, most compilers issue a diagnostic but continue processing the source file until they reach the end of the file.    There can often come a point, after the compiler has issued several diagnostics, that it is in a strange state, so subsequent diagnostics have little relationship to the code being processed.

The approach to address this is simple - find and correct the first diagnostic the compiler issues, not the last.   It doesn't matter if the error messages are associated with multiple header files - after preprocessing, the compiler processes code sequentially, so the first error messages it reports are the first it finds.

A significant number of developers - and not exclusively beginners either - start at the bottom of a large screen of diagnostics (or, for example, a scrollable window) and work up the screen.   That effectively starts at the last diagnostic issued by the compiler, not the first - a point at which the compiler is most likely to be confused and issuing diagnostics that have little relationship to the code.   Instead, it is necessary to scroll up the screen, find the first diagnostic issued, and address that first.

Some compilers support options to stop compiling after some specified number of errors.   Such options can be used to limit the number of errors reported, and therefore reduce the chances of confused error messages.   However, this is often only partly effective, since there is no hard and fast rule about the number of errors that trigger compiler confusion.    The real solution, as I said above, is to get in the habit of finding the first error message and addressing that, rather than trying to work backward from the last error message.